# Adding custom separator height to UITableViewCell not working when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a custom cell separator to only the **first row** (where all requested surfaces is) of the table. Whenever I scroll however, the thick grey line appears in other rows as well sometime. How do I keep that from happening?

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method I have this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && [cell.dicInfo[AIRCRAFTSURFACE_SURFACE] isEqualToString:@"ALL REQUESTED SURFACES"]) {
            cell.lblSurface.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:16.0f];
            CGRect sizeRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            NSInteger separatorHeight = 10;
            additionalSeparator.frame = CGRectMake(0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height-separatorHeight,sizeRect.size.width,separatorHeight);
            additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:additionalSeparator];
}
```

I have the `UIView *additionalSeparator;` initialized on `viewDidLoad`.

Could it be because the cells are being reused and that causes something to happen?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's because the cells are reused. You add the subview the first time row 0 is requested... when you scroll, that cell is reused for, perhaps, row 6... but you did not remove the subview. Personally, I would make 3 cell types:  "Title Row" "Separator Row" and "Line Item Row". Then I don't have to worry about it (plus it's a much cleaner way of going about it than creating / adding subviews inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an else statement to remove your separator in other rows.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     UIView *additionalSeparator = [[UIView alloc] init....];
     additionalSeparator.tag = 9999;
     .
     .
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
     .
     .
     additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
     [cell addSubview:additionalSeparator];
  } else {
    [[cell viewWithTag:9999] removeFromSuperView];
  }
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, however it seems to still cut off the orange and green box (which are part of the cell). I tried to adjust the height of the cell by using `cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height + 10);` but that does not seem to work. 
Can you help with that?

Comment: You need to add constraints to fix that which is not part of you original question.